# usage parity-db instead of rocksdb

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, blockchain, rocks-db

in the `substrate-node-template` case , I don't want to compile rocks-db at all. how it would be possible compile parity-db instead of rocks-db?

Comment: That would be so cool. Then you would need less things natively installed on your machine to get started.

Answer (score 2):

To compile the Substrate Node Template with Parity DB instead of RocksDB, you'll need to make the following changes:

1. Update `Cargo.toml`: Open the `Cargo.toml` file in the Substrate Node Template project and modify the dependencies section. Remove the `rocksdb` dependency and add the `parity-db` dependency instead. Your `Cargo.toml` file should look something like this:

   ```
   [dependencies]
   # Remove the rocksdb dependency
   # rocksdb = { version = "0.6", optional = true, features = ["full"] }

   # Add the parity-db dependency
   parity-db = { version = "2.1", optional = true }
   ```
2. Update `lib.rs`: Open the `lib.rs` file (or the main file of your substrate node) and update the storage configuration. Replace the `RocksDb` storage configuration with `ParityDb`. Here's an example:

   ```rust
   use substrate_node_template_runtime::{
       // Replace `RocksDb` with `ParityDb`
       ParityDb, Runtime,
   };

   const PARITY_DB_CONFIG: &'static str = r#"
   {
       "path": "./parity_db",
       "cache_size": 536870912,
       "write_buffer_size": 268435456,
       "max_open_files": 10000,
       "block_cache_size": 268435456,
       "disable_block_cache": false,
       "max_table_size": 268435456,
       "block_size": 4096,
       "paranoid_checks": false,
       "verify_checksums": true,
       "max_background_compactions": 10,
       "num_levels": 7,
       "level_compaction_dynamic_level_bytes": true,
       "level_compaction_trigger": 4,
       "level_compaction_files": 10,
       "disable_auto_compactions": false,
       "soft_pending_compaction_bytes_limit": 68719476736,
       "hard_pending_compaction_bytes_limit": 274877906944,
       "force_consistency_checks": false,
       "use_fsync": false,
       "db_log_path": "",
       "read_amp_bytes_per_bit": 0
   }
   "#;

   #[tokio::main]
   async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
       // Replace `RocksDb` with `ParityDb` in the storage configuration
       let _ = SubstrateNodeTemplateRuntime::from_storage(
           ParityDb::open(Path::new("./parity_db"), PARITY_DB_CONFIG.parse().unwrap())?,
       )?;

       // Rest of your code
   }
   ```

   In this example, the `ParityDb` storage configuration is used instead of `RocksDb`. Adjust the path and other configuration options based on your requirements.

Comment: if it's possible to build the substrate-node-template without Rocksdb using your solution, then why is there still this open issue https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13354 that claims we can't build Substrate without having to pull in Rocksdb and all of its native dependencies?